# How do I create a Google Datastore index without creating an App Engine application?

Tags: google-app-engine

I understand that you can [create a datastore-indices.xml file](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig) in your WEB-INF folder, and if that gets uploaded to Google App Engine the indices will be autogenerated. However, in my use case, I'm not using Google App Engine but still using Google Datastore. Is there a way to define custom indices without having to make a new App Engine project, define the indices, and upload it?

Comment: Since you're not using App Engine, I'm assuming you're using the separate Cloud Datastore API - in which case, does [this](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/) help?  (In short, the `gcd` tool allows you to manage indexes).

Comment: Thanks! This looks like the tool I was looking for :).

Comment: @tx802 please add you comment as an answer so the op can accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not using App Engine, you will be using the standalone [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview) API.

With this you don't need to touch App Engine at all.  So, to create your index definitions, you will need the [`gcd`](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/) tool.

The index definition and management is very similar to the process with App Engine Datastore - you can find more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig).